# How to build a jQuery-powered switcher to add/remove css attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a box container that expands when clicking in a "read more" button and collapse to the initial size when clicking in the same button (now a "collapse" button).

In the DOM I have a `.leer-mas` button inside a `.post` container. And the following jQuery code:

```
//When link with class .leer-mas is clicked, get the parent element's id and add some css attributes
$('.leer-mas').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.post');
    item.css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).addClass('leer-menos');
    $(this).text('Leer menos');         
});


//When link with class .leer-mas is clicked, get the parent element's id and remove some css attributes
$('.leer-mas.leer-menos').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.post');
    item.removeAttr('height');
    $(this).removeClass('leer-menos');
})
```

The first action works like a charm. But the second action does nothing... And I think I'm missing some fundamentals of jQuery, as the syntax is identical and maybe that is not the way it should be :)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit - I had a few errors on my code. Though I'm still trying to get it with a single switcher, I have a working version.

New DOM looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="leer mas">
    </div>
    <div class="leer menos">
    </div>
</div>
```

The code now looks like this:

```
//When link with class .leer-mas is clicked, get the parent element's id (which is also that element's id in the database)
$('.leer.mas').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.post');
    //Send the id to the PHP script, which returns 1 if successful and 0 if not
    item.css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('.leer.menos').show();
});


//When link with class .leer-mas is clicked, get the parent element's id (which is also that element's id in the database)
$('.leer.menos').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.post');
    //Send the id to the PHP script, which returns 1 if successful and 0 if not
    item.removeAttr('style');
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev('.leer.mas').show();
});
```

This works smoothly. But If I get it working with the intended structure of the original question (with a single button), i would be happier :)

Comment: you can use toggle class inside the first one

Answer (score 2):

it is because the class `leer-menos` is added dynamically... so when the event registration code is executed there is no element with classes `leer-mas` and `leer-menos`.

A possible solution is to use event delegation

```
//When link with class .leer-mas is clicked, get the parent element's id and remove some css attributes
$(document).on('click', '.leer-mas.leer-menos', function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.post');
    item.removeAttr('height');
    $(this).removeClass('leer-menos');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. Sure trying to select a class that was dynamically added and that wasn't there when the "ready" status triggered is not helping :) I didnt get your code to work, either inside the $(document).ready statement or right after it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `.removeAttr()` to remove a CSS Property within the attribute "Style". This is incorrect, try using `item.removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you can draw ideas from this:

```
$('.leer-mas').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest('.post');
    // toggle "height" between 'auto' and null
    item.css('height', item.css('height') == 'auto' ? null : 'auto' );
    // toggle class 'leer-menos'
    $(this).toggleClass('leer-menos');
    // toggle text between 'Leer menos' and ''
    $(this).text( $(this).is('.leer-menos') ? 'Leer menos' : '' );         
});
```

Comment: This is clever, really few lines and it is supposed to do exactly what I was looking for. But I didnt got it working :)

Comment: How don't? What is happening? This should work, maybe there's some typo or something I left behind, because I didn't tested it. If you bring a JSFiddle we can look at it.